# Storing arbitrary data in the iOS Keychain

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, keychain

I'm planning to allow for a trial period in my new app before you have to pay to use it. Instead of wasting time on setting up a complex server architecture that will do this, can i simply store the first run date in the Keychain?

Questions:

1) Will this information persist between app deletes and reinstalls, and device wipes provided that you restore a backup?

2) Does Apple generally approve storing this kind of data in the Keychain? I'm getting a feeling that this could be a potential problem since you are leaving data behind after deleting the app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store a string in KeyChain , iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios)

Comment: Keychain items can now even be synced via iCloud so you could in theory prevent a specific user from ever running the app again. However, Apple's policy on trials is a different story (and off-topic here on SO). You should try [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/devforums/) for such questions.

Comment: Why don't you use NSUserDefaults instead of KeyChain?

Comment: @Paul because it's wiped when you reinstall the app. In that case the user could just delete the app, download it again and keep using it for free.

Comment: @FilipRadelic We already have this functionality in the App Store, but it's server backed and we don't want the current solution in the new backend and app.